# How to delete specific meta_key filed and their value(s) from UserMeta table in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, metadata, meta-key

I have added 
"add_user_meta( $userid, 'last_login',$current_login_time);" 
instead of 
"update_user_meta( $userid, 'last_login',$current_login_time);".

Now scenario is I have plenty of MetaKey fields as 'last_login'.

Please advise how can I delete all meta_key i.e. 'last_login' and just keep one the most recent?

Need code or mysql query.

Every help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It's often quicker to construct a new table selecting just the data you wish to retain - although I appreciate, that this is a little trickier in an EAV environment.

Comment: Surely, entity-atttribute is defined as unique - so I'm puzzled as to how this error could have occurred !?!

Answer (score 1):

you can delete this through mysql query

```
DELETE 
FROM    wp_usermeta 
WHERE   meta_key = 'last_login'
```

and if you use `update_user_meta`, the next your function will run, it would automatically create user meta if it doesn't exist and will update if it exist so it wont create duplicates

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer as this will delete add metakeys named 'last_login' but i have to keep most recent.